# SVG filter in Safari in 2023? (Blob/gooey effect)

Tags: css, animation, svg, safari, cross-browser

I found this cool CodePen where they use SVG filters to create blob a effect, but it's not working in Safari:

https://codepen.io/r0st1kuzh/pen/mrJoZz

```
 <svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="18" result="blur" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 28 -10" result="filter" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="filter" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

 .blob {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     filter: url('#filter');
}
```

The same effect can be done using contrast and blur filters, but I was hoping to use the SVG.

https://codepen.io/kennsorr/pen/vYVYOMV

Comment: See my [blog post](https://browser-unplugged.net/blog/gooeybugs.en.html) for several rewrites of that filter effect. You can test cross-browser compatibility with [this pen](https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/jaRGze).